# autocomplete textbox when down arrow key pressed

Tags: autocomplete

I have used auto complete textbox previously. That auto complete works only when i hit the character keys. Like :

```
$('#<%= txtSiteName.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "WebService.asmx/GetAllSites",
                data: "{'keywords':'"+ + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    //alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

But now i want to dropdown the autocomplete when i hit the DOWN ARROW KEY.
Please help me :)
and Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind it like so

```
$('input').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      $('#search').catcomplete('search', $('#search').val());
    }
});
```

Assuming your search box has the id of "search".

Although there may be a way doing it with the existing binding using the focus method that may be worth looking into.

Comment: Sir i understand what you said .............
But the thing is i dont know how to bind in the above jscript :(
Could you please help..... :)

Comment: In the above script you would need to change 'input' and '#search' to your search boxes id, in your case '#<%= txtSiteName.ClientID %>'

Comment: I recently found out one more problem :(
The above mentioned jquery is not working with Firefox...
Its working fine with IE and chrome